# Passing multiple arguments to a scriptblock in Start-Jobs command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, start-job

I am trying to pass multiple arguments to my scriptblock:

```
$ConfigFile = @("C:\zip1.zip","C:\zip2.zip")
$unzippath = "C:\"
$ScriptBlock = {
  param($ConfigFile,$unzippath) 
  $shell = new-object -com shell.application
  $zip = $shell.NameSpace($ConfigFile)
  foreach($item in $zip.items())
  {
     $shell.Namespace($unzippath).copyhere($item)
  }
}

Start-Job -Scriptblock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ConfigFile,$unzippath
```

But its failing. Can someone help me?

Comment: You are doing it right. What error do you get?

Comment: Does your script work without `Start-Job`? I really doubt that `$shell.NameSpace` accept array as parameter.

Comment: It works if I pass $ConfigFile as single path instead of array. But when I pass an array, it fails..

Comment: Is there anyway I can pass an array ??

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right and `$ConfigFile` is passed as an `array`. So your issue is *not about passing parameters* to the `scriptblock`. Its rather about how can you extract multiple zip files using `Shell.application`.

You probably have to iterate over each zip using the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet and extract it:

```
$ConfigFile = @("C:\zip1.zip","C:\zip2.zip")
 $unzippath = "C:\"
 $ScriptBlock = {
    param($ConfigFile,$unzippath) 
    $ConfigFile | ForEach-Object {
        $shell = new-object -com shell.application
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($_)
        foreach($item in $zip.items())
        {
           $shell.Namespace($unzippath).copyhere($item)
        }
    }
  }

  Start-Job -Scriptblock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ConfigFile,$unzippath
```